# Strapi: How to get one entry by id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, content-management-system, strapi

I'm currently working on a website using Strapi as a CMS and Next.js (React) in Frontend. The site also has an image slider which obviously contains an image, a headline and a description. These three things I now want to get from my Strapi Collection Type called Banner (Banners). I already created a function to do that, but it only returns all three entries (all titles of all Id's for example).

So how can I filter the request to get only one entry from one specific Id? The current code looks like the following: (file: `/components/image-slider.js`)

```js
import React from "react";

const Slider = ({ }) => {
    const [banners, setBanners] = React.useState(null);
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const getBanners = async() => {
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/banners/");
            const json = await res.json();
            setBanners(json);
        }
       
        getBanners();
    }, [])

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        // makes image slider working
    }
        
    return (
        <div className="img-slider">
            <div className="slide active">
                <div className="info">
                    {banners ? banners.map((banner) => (
                        <h2 key={banner.Id}>{banner.Title}</h2>
                    )) : (
                        <div>Loading...</div>
                    )}
                    {banners ? banners.map((banner) => (
                        <p key={banner.Id}>{banner.Content}</p>
                    )) : (
                        <div>Loading...</div>
                    )}                   
                </div>
                {/* Until now I didn't try to get an image, because of the error I'm currently facing */}
            </div>
            <div className="slide">
                <div className="info">
                    {banners ? banners.map((banner) => (
                        <h2 key={banner.Id}>{banner.Title}</h2>
                    )) : (
                        <div>Loading...</div>
                    )}
                    {banners ? banners.map((banner) => (
                        <h2 key={banner.Id}>{banner.Content}</h2>
                    )) : (
                        <div>Loading...</div>
                    )}
                    {/* Until now I didn't try to get an image, because of the error I'm currently facing */}
                </div>
            </div>
            {/* Futher slides */}
            <div className="navigation">
                <div className="btn-navig active"></div>
                <div className="btn-navig"></div>
                <div className="btn-navig"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
    
export default Slider;
```

*Update:*
The data I get back from the Strapi API looks like the following: (It's just filled with sample images, titles and descriptions...)

```json
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "Title":"Musik",
      "Content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
      "published_at":"2021-04-23T07:32:10.839Z",
      "created_at":"2021-04-23T07:32:08.130Z",
      "updated_at":"2021-04-23T07:32:10.883Z",
      "Cover":[
         {
            "id":9,
            "name":"we-love-pizza.jpg",
            "alternativeText":null,
            "caption":null,
            "width":3782,
            "height":2522,
            "formats":{
               "thumbnail":{
                  "name":"thumbnail_we-love-pizza.jpg",
                  "hash":"thumbnail_we_love_pizza_d16dd21274",
                  "ext":".jpg",
                  "mime":"image/jpeg",
                  "width":234,
                  "height":156,
                  "size":13.75,
                  "path":null,
                  "url":"/uploads/thumbnail_we_love_pizza_d16dd21274.jpg"
               },
               "large":{
                  "name":"large_we-love-pizza.jpg",
                  "hash":"large_we_love_pizza_d16dd21274",
                  "ext":".jpg",
                  "mime":"image/jpeg",
                  "width":1000,
                  "height":667,
                  "size":180.46,
                  "path":null,
                  "url":"/uploads/large_we_love_pizza_d16dd21274.jpg"
               },
               "medium":{
                  "name":"medium_we-love-pizza.jpg",
                  "hash":"medium_we_love_pizza_d16dd21274",
                  "ext":".jpg",
                  "mime":"image/jpeg",
                  "width":750,
                  "height":500,
                  "size":106.25,
                  "path":null,
                  "url":"/uploads/medium_we_love_pizza_d16dd21274.jpg"
               },
               "small":{
                  "name":"small_we-love-pizza.jpg",
                  "hash":"small_we_love_pizza_d16dd21274",
                  "ext":".jpg",
                  "mime":"image/jpeg",
                  "width":500,
                  "height":333,
                  "size":52.59,
                  "path":null,
                  "url":"/uploads/small_we_love_pizza_d16dd21274.jpg"
               }
            },
            "hash":"we_love_pizza_d16dd21274",
            "ext":".jpg",
            "mime":"image/jpeg",
            "size":955.02,
            "url":"/uploads/we_love_pizza_d16dd21274.jpg",
            "previewUrl":null,
            "provider":"local",
            "provider_metadata":null,
            "created_at":"2021-04-20T17:42:20.277Z",
            "updated_at":"2021-04-20T17:42:20.277Z"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "Title":"Sport",
      "Content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
      "published_at":"2021-04-24T11:56:58.633Z",
      "created_at":"2021-04-24T11:56:56.191Z",
      "updated_at":"2021-04-24T11:56:58.697Z",
      "Cover":[
         {
            "id":8,
            "name":"beautiful-picture.jpg",
            "alternativeText":null,
            "caption":null,
            "width":3824,
            "height":2548,
            "formats":{
               "thumbnail":{
                  "name":"thumbnail_beautiful-picture.jpg",
                  "hash":"thumbnail_beautiful_picture_06a43830c6",
                  "ext":".jpg",
                  "mime":"image/jpeg",
                  "width":234,
                  "height":156,
                  "size":6.44,
                  "path":null,
                  "url":"/uploads/thumbnail_beautiful_picture_06a43830c6.jpg"
               },
               "large":{
                  "name":"large_beautiful-picture.jpg",
                  "hash":"large_beautiful_picture_06a43830c6",
                  "ext":".jpg",
                  "mime":"image/jpeg",
                  "width":1000,
                  "height":666,
                  "size":83.56,
                  "path":null,
                  "url":"/uploads/large_beautiful_picture_06a43830c6.jpg"
               },
               "medium":{
                  "name":"medium_beautiful-picture.jpg",
                  "hash":"medium_beautiful_picture_06a43830c6",
                  "ext":".jpg",
                  "mime":"image/jpeg",
                  "width":750,
                  "height":500,
                  "size":47.82,
                  "path":null,
                  "url":"/uploads/medium_beautiful_picture_06a43830c6.jpg"
               },
               "small":{
                  "name":"small_beautiful-picture.jpg",
                  "hash":"small_beautiful_picture_06a43830c6",
                  "ext":".jpg",
                  "mime":"image/jpeg",
                  "width":500,
                  "height":333,
                  "size":23.36,
                  "path":null,
                  "url":"/uploads/small_beautiful_picture_06a43830c6.jpg"
               }
            },
            "hash":"beautiful_picture_06a43830c6",
            "ext":".jpg",
            "mime":"image/jpeg",
            "size":585.12,
            "url":"/uploads/beautiful_picture_06a43830c6.jpg",
            "previewUrl":null,
            "provider":"local",
            "provider_metadata":null,
            "created_at":"2021-04-20T17:42:20.163Z",
            "updated_at":"2021-04-20T17:42:20.163Z"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "Title":"Kunst",
      "Content":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
      "published_at":"2021-04-24T11:57:31.725Z",
      "created_at":"2021-04-24T11:57:15.225Z",
      "updated_at":"2021-04-24T11:57:31.794Z",
      "Cover":[
         {
            "id":6,
            "name":"this-shrimp-is-awesome.jpg",
            "alternativeText":null,
            "caption":null,
            "width":1200,
            "height":630,
            "formats":{
               "thumbnail":{
                  "name":"thumbnail_this-shrimp-is-awesome.jpg",
                  "hash":"thumbnail_this_shrimp_is_awesome_4167fb0adc",
                  "ext":".jpg",
                  "mime":"image/jpeg",
                  "width":245,
                  "height":129,
                  "size":9.43,
                  "path":null,
                  "url":"/uploads/thumbnail_this_shrimp_is_awesome_4167fb0adc.jpg"
               },
               "large":{
                  "name":"large_this-shrimp-is-awesome.jpg",
                  "hash":"large_this_shrimp_is_awesome_4167fb0adc",
                  "ext":".jpg",
                  "mime":"image/jpeg",
                  "width":1000,
                  "height":525,
                  "size":72.87,
                  "path":null,
                  "url":"/uploads/large_this_shrimp_is_awesome_4167fb0adc.jpg"
               },
               "medium":{
                  "name":"medium_this-shrimp-is-awesome.jpg",
                  "hash":"medium_this_shrimp_is_awesome_4167fb0adc",
                  "ext":".jpg",
                  "mime":"image/jpeg",
                  "width":750,
                  "height":394,
                  "size":48.38,
                  "path":null,
                  "url":"/uploads/medium_this_shrimp_is_awesome_4167fb0adc.jpg"
               },
               "small":{
                  "name":"small_this-shrimp-is-awesome.jpg",
                  "hash":"small_this_shrimp_is_awesome_4167fb0adc",
                  "ext":".jpg",
                  "mime":"image/jpeg",
                  "width":500,
                  "height":263,
                  "size":26.69,
                  "path":null,
                  "url":"/uploads/small_this_shrimp_is_awesome_4167fb0adc.jpg"
               }
            },
            "hash":"this_shrimp_is_awesome_4167fb0adc",
            "ext":".jpg",
            "mime":"image/jpeg",
            "size":95.48,
            "url":"/uploads/this_shrimp_is_awesome_4167fb0adc.jpg",
            "previewUrl":null,
            "provider":"local",
            "provider_metadata":null,
            "created_at":"2021-04-20T17:42:19.639Z",
            "updated_at":"2021-04-20T17:42:19.639Z"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: If you know the  specific id, I guess you can just fetch http://localhost:1337/banners/[id]?
The strapi API documentation is pretty useful https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/content-api.html#get-an-entry

Comment: Yes, thanks but how do I put this into my code? I want to get all entries of all three Id's, but in every slider only the title etc. with a specifi Id...

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the issue is. Is the problem fetching a single entry from Strapi API, or displaying the entries in the slider one-by-one? Also, what does the data you get back from the API look like?

Comment: I'm sorry for that... But the problem is fetching a single entry from the Strapi API... In my slider, all titles and descriptions from the three Id's are displayed underneath each other... So now I want to only get the title and the description from the first Id for the first slide and so on... I just updated my question with the data I get back from the API.